# Select data in single table with a 1:Many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a table with 67 columns and around 36,000 rows, I need to run a SELECT based on two of those columns.

The important columns are FINANCIAL_ACCOUNT_ID, EVENT_DESCRIPTION.

The FINANCIAL_ACCOUNT_ID is a unique number per account, but may not be unique in the table. Event Description is not unique. Event Description can contain 'Event 1' 'Event 2' 'Event 3' and so on.

So the table could look like this:

```
TABLE
+----------------------+-------------------+-------------+
| FINANCIAL_ACCOUNT_ID | EVENT_DESCRIPTION | OTHER_STUFF |
+----------------------+-------------------+-------------+
|  1121                |   Event 1         |     n/a     |
|  107401              |   Event 2         |     n/a     |
|  256483              |   Event 1         |     n/a     |
|  1121                |   Event 3         |     n/a     |
|  107401              |   Event 1         |     n/a     |
|  363586              |   Event 1         |     n/a     |
|  546875              |   Event 1         |     n/a     |
|  546875              |   Event 2         |     n/a     |
+----------------------+-------------------+-------------+


RESULT
+----------------------+-------------------+-------------+
| FINANCIAL_ACCOUNT_ID | EVENT_DESCRIPTION | OTHER_STUFF |
+----------------------+-------------------+-------------+
|  107401              |   Event 2         |     n/a     |
|  107401              |   Event 1         |     n/a     |
|  546875              |   Event 1         |     n/a     |
|  546875              |   Event 2         |     n/a     |
+----------------------+-------------------+-------------+
```

What I need to get returned is the entire row IF there is a financial account ID with BOTH 'Event 1' and 'Event 2'.

I've tried WITH clauses combined with inner joins... In my latest attempt, I've added a count(financial_account_id) such as:

```
 select FINANCIAL_ACCOUNT_ID, EVENT_DESCRIPTION, COUNT(FINANCIAL_ACCOUNT_ID)
 FROM master 
 group by FINANCIAL_ACCOUNT_ID 
 HAVING COUNT(FINANCIAL_ACCOUNT_ID) >1;
```

However, here are the results I'm seeing with that select statement:

```
Financial_Account_ID | Event_Description | COUNT(Financial_Account_ID)
      107401         |      Event 2      |         2
      546875         |      Event 1      |         2
```

(I say I need the entire row, but once I get the proper results returned, I can filter out the extraneous columns I don't need.)

Any help with what a SQL Query like this should look like?
Details: mariadb 10, databasename: JuneEvents, table name: master
I've also got a copy in a MS-SQL 2012 Express db

EDIT: @Tim - Sorry for that, I need to match each account to both 'event 1' and 'event 2' tossing event 3 and any others that may exist. Does that clarify?

SOLUTION: 
I used @Gordon's 2nd query with the JOIN as a jumping off point and ended up with a final query that looked like this: (note: there are now some extra fields, but I added them after the initial query returned the propper results from the initial dataset.)

```
SELECT t.financial_account_id, t.event_description, t.sold_quantity, t.paid_amount
FROM master t JOIN
     (SELECT financial_account_id
      FROM master t
      WHERE event_description IN ('Event 1', 'Event 2') 
      GROUP BY financial_account_id
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT event_description) = 2
     ) tt
     ON tt.financial_account_id = t.financial_account_id
     WHERE (event_description IN ('Event 1', 'Event 2') AND (sold_quantity > 0));
```

Comment: You never gave us the logic for determining _which_ `Event_Description` to return in the final result.

Comment: The `GROUP BY` is very powerful, but so is using any datetime column to help you distinquish the results.

Depending on the way Event_1 and Event_2 are split (can they happen at the same time? Can NULL values occur?), you might need to use an subquery.

Clearly, we need more details on the business logic and rules.

Comment: @RCMaples so are you saying you want to match account which have events 1 and 2, and _only_ events 1 and 2?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @RCMaples Have a look at my updated answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the accounts with both events, use:

```
SELECT financial_account_id
FROM master t
WHERE event_description IN ('Event 1', 'Event 2')
GROUP BY financial_account_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT event_description) = 2;
```

Then to get the original rows, use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM master t JOIN
     (SELECT financial_account_id
      FROM master t
      WHERE event_description IN ('Event 1', 'Event 2')
      GROUP BY financial_account_id
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT event_description) = 2
     ) tt
     ON tt.financial_account_id = t.financial_account_id;
```

Comment: I used your 2nd query with the JOIN and ended up with a final query that looked like this:

    SELECT t.financial_account_id, t.event_description, t.sold_quantity, t.paid_amount
    FROM master t JOIN
         (SELECT financial_account_id
          FROM master t
          WHERE event_description IN ('Event 1', 'Event 2') 
          GROUP BY financial_account_id
          HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT event_description) = 2
         ) tt
         ON tt.financial_account_id = t.financial_account_id
         WHERE (event_description IN ('Event 1', 'Event 2') AND (sold_quantity > 0));

Answer (score 0):

The following query will yield all `FINANCIAL_ACCOUNT_ID` which have both `'Event 1'` and `'Event 2'`, and *only* those two events.  If you want to pull in other information, you can easily join this result to another table.

```
SELECT FINANCIAL_ACCOUNT_ID,
    SUM(CASE WHEN EVENT_DESCRIPTION IN ('Event 1', 'Event 2') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS eventCount
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY FINANCIAL_ACCOUNT_ID
HAVING eventCount = 2 AND COUNT(*) = 2
```